# How to display the error message obtained from @Column (unique = true)?

Tags: java, jpa

I use JPA technology in my project.

Here is the entity:

```
@Entity
public class Cars implements Serializable {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idCars")
    private long idCars;

    @Column(name="nomCars",unique=true)
    private String nomCars;
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/Cars")
public class CarsRestController {

@RequestMapping(value="/AddCars")
    public Cars AddCars(Cars cr){

        return repository.save(cr);
    }
}
```

I used the `unique = true` attribute to check if the new `Cars` object exists or does not exist in the DB. In case the object exists I want to retrieve this error message to display it after the web user.

Thanks,

Comment: You can handle exception but I'd rather write a custom JSR-303 validator that will do this check for me before executing a code in a controller.

Comment: I do not know JSR-303, can you explain to me how to do JPA annotation? @Slava Semushin

Comment: The error you get from JPA would be provider and database dependent.  You'll have to experiment and parse the error yourself, but this is the most efficient option IMO.  The JSR-303 validation specification has examples if you want to go that approach (http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/), and there are examples and demos out there, but I don't know that it'll work well for this as you'll have to query the database upfront anyway, and it can get added after your validation query ran.  Or you can just query for the name before you try to insert or after you get an error to see if it exists.

Comment: I will try, thanks @Chris

Comment: Which annotation I used to ensure object validation? `Public cars AddCars (Cars cr) {...}` @Chris